# Compare three voltages by using comparator

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, comparator

I am working on a circuit which compares three voltages V(a), V(b) and V(c) by using only op-amps.
To result

- If V(a)>V(b)>V(c) , V(output) should be 15v
- If V(a)>V(c)>V(b) , V(output) should be 15v

---

- If V(b)>V(a)>V(c) , V(output) should be 10v
- If V(b)>V(c)>V(a) , V(output) should be 10v

---

- If V(c)>V(a)>V(b) , V(output) should be 5v
- If V(c)>V(b)>V(a) , V(output) should be 5v

This can be done by using transistor and op amps to get lower or higher voltage together but is there solution for that by using just op amps?
[image]

---

edited

---

With this I can compare three voltages and get the higher or lower voltage.

Comment: yes, there is. Why shouldn't there be? What's your transistor-based circuit? Notice that an Opamp in open loop configuration is just a comparator.

Comment: Show the circuit with transistors which you think works.

Comment: this question smells like school work. is it?

Comment: Sounds like the same point a solar panel in one of three directions based on input from three LDRs I have been seeing for the past week or so.

Comment: Are diodes ok?..

Comment: resistors, capacitors, inductors, diodes, op-amps are ok

Comment: "Sounds like the same point a solar panel in one of three directions based on input from three LDRs I have been seeing for the past week or so" my real point making some circuit like that but ı couldnt figure out

Comment: FWIW yes http://tinyurl.com/y8hezu6m with 1 quad Op Amp and no pots

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Your biggest issue is getting accurate 15, 10 and 5V values when the max and min output values of op-amps is vague.

Hence the need for pots in this answer.

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VtSP1vLha4qDJqrf_lNPX-5u93ZF-C9f/view?usp=sharing  I tried to to your circuit like this but it doenst work properly

Comment: @I think I got the 20/10 dividers backwards, or rather forgot to switch them round. e,g, R11/R12